# Exibir um loader enquanto processa o ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tem como mostrar uma mensagem do tipo: "Carregando..." enquanto meu ajax faz a operação?

**AJAX**

```
              $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',                   
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("sucesso");
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("erro");
                }   
              });
```

tipo, antes de entrar no `success: function(data){}` mostrar um loader ou uma msg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
 $("div").html("<img src='imagem_gif_carregando.gif'>");
   $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',                   
                success: function(data) {
                    $("div").html("Requisição concluída");
                    console.log("sucesso");
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log("erro");
                }   
              });
```

Colocar uma imagem dentro de uma `<div></div>` antes de fazer a requisição

```
 $("div").html("<img src='imagem_gif_carregando.gif'>");
```

E depois que a requisição acabar remover a imagem da div

```
$("div").html("Requisição concluída");
```

Answer (score 10):

Para além da resposta do Silvio, tens ainda outra forma válida de o fazer, usando o método *beforeSend* na requisição:

```
<div id="divCorpo"></div>

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',  
    beforeSend: function () {
        //Aqui adicionas o loader
        $("#divCorpo").html("<img src='imagem_gif_carregando.gif'>");
    },         
    success: function(data) {
       console.log("sucesso");
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("erro");
    }   
 });
```

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha, dá também uma vista de olhos nesta outra solução :) No entanto, a tua resposta também responde bem ao pedido!

Comment: Sim, verdade. Não conhecia esse `beforeSend` é que como sempre uso o `$.post` ao invés do `$.ajax` faço do primeiro modo, por no $.post não tem esse `beforeSend` `+1`