# Como fazer uma barra de progresso?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho uma página que é carregada via load do jQuery. Dentro desta página existe uma consulta SQL que demora em média 8 segundos.

Gostaria de colocar algum indicativo que a consulta está carregando, pode ser uma barra de progresso, exibir porcentagem, um circulo rodando, qualquer coisa. Dei uma procurada no Goolge mas não encontrei nada que me ajuda. Alguém conhece alguma forma de fazer isso?

Script que carrega a página:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clica').click(function(){
        $('#new').load('opcoesConsultaSiga.php?cond='+$(this).val());
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<button class="clica" value="-1">Exibir Tudo</button>
<button class="clica" value="2">Ordenar por estoque </button>
<button class="clica" value="4">Ordenar por custo </button>
<div id="new"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A forma mais simples de fazer isso seria adicionando um ícone de loading...

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   
  $("#carregar").on('click', function(){

    $("#loading").fadeIn('fast');

    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#loading").fadeOut('fast');
    }, 5000);

  });

});
```

```css
#loading {
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:50% 0;
  margin:0;
  text-align:center;
}

#loading img{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:-8px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="carregar">Carregar</button>
<div id="loading">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4BUx.gif" alt="Carregando..." title="Carregando...">
</div>
```

### [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/048gqkxk/)

Então bastaria abrir o `loading` antes da execução do AJAX, e oculta-lo quando estiver completo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.clica').click(function(){
   $("#loading").fadeIn('fast'); // Exibi o loading antes da requisição
      $.ajax({
         url: 'opcoesConsultaSiga.php?',
         type: 'GET',
         data: {cond: $(this).val()},
         success: function(data){
            $('#new').html(data);
         },
         error: function(x, y, z){
            $('#new').html($('<p />').text('Erro ao processar requisição: ' + y));
         },
         complete: function(){
            $("#loading").fadeOut('fast'); // Oculta o loading ao terminar a requisição
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta @KaduAmaral, fiz uma atualização na pergunta explicando melhor o problema e coloquei meu código. De acordo com o código que tenho, onde poderia colocar o `$("#loading").fadeOut('fast');`?? Tentei fazer de uma forma semelhante que tinha encontrado antes e não deu certo.

Comment: Oi @AmandaLima, atualizei a resposta com a tua requisição... Testa e veja se funciona (visto que não testei...). ;)

Comment: Funcionou, obrigada! Porém coloquei `$("#loading").fadeIn('fast'); `  dentro de `$('.clica').click(function(){`

Comment: Isso, na verdade deveria ser ali mesmo, ficou errado na resposta. vou corrigir. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Podes usar o método ready do jQuery.

Crias uma div com um "loader" a seguir ao body e depois escondes assim que a página tenha sido completamente carregada.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#divLoader').hide();
});
```

Também podes usar o .ajaxStart() / .ajaxStop()

[jQuery Ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

[jQuery Ajax Start/Ajax Stop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

[Duplicata, Post com um problema semelhante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54866/exibir-um-loader-enquanto-processa-o-ajax?lq=1)