# Como faço para colocar um loading responsivo

Tags: php, html, ajax

Meu site ele está todo feito preciso colocar um loading quando a pessoa clica em cada aba ou até mesmo pra entrar no site

So que não achei nem um tutorial de como faz pois ele funciona tanto pra celular e tanto pra computador..

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem o que voce necessita, voce pode colocar uma mensagem antes de fazer uma requisição ajax como mostra o link a seguir:

[Exibir um loader enquanto processa o ajax](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54866/exibir-um-loader-enquanto-processa-o-ajax)

Comment: Ele tem que ser responsivel, por exemplo quero que ele abre uma tela branca com a mensagem de carregamento com gif e depois de um tempo de 3500 seria o timer né ele aparecia a pagina depois deste tempo